# Using ADLDS on Windows 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7

I don't know if this should be here or in superuser as one of my other questions were; anyway an administrator will just move it :D.

So, I would like to know if it's possible to install ADLDS on Windows 7, in order to use it as a server.

The feature I would like to retain is the logging in of any of the AD users in any of the PCs in the network connected to the "server".

Do you think that's possible? The reason why I don't want to use Win2k8r2 anymore is that it consumes too much extra RAM for my taste; and I don't really need it.

Comment: AD LDS is really not usable as a domain controller.  Server 2008 R2 can run quite happily in 1GB of RAM for light usage; that really is such a small amount of RAM that it should be insignificant in any professional environment.  Questions about things in an unprofessional environment are off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=a45059af-47a8-4c96-afe3-93dab7b5b658

Comment: Yeah, I already have that site; I didn't ask for the link, but if it's possible to do what I asked above..

Meaning that when I create users on the ADLDS, will I be able to use those users on the other PCs connected to the "server" to connect to Windows on that PC?

Comment: well the answer to your question is in the link, you just need to read a little.

Comment: windows 7 with adlds will use more ram then w2k8r2 core with the ad role added.

Comment: huh, I read the whole thing but I didn't get my answer.. maybe i'm even worse than I thought concerning those network issues..

so it would be better if I used only w2k8r2 core instead of the whole thing?

Comment: ok I've reread what your asking an adlds is not designed for what your trying to do.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess I'll have to install Core in that case; at least there would not be tons of things I don't use.